# What are the (dis)advantages of early bound?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm researching the pros and cons of early and late binding in CRM. I've got a good idea on the subject but there are some points I'm unclear about.

1. Some say that early biding is the fastest, other that lates is. Is there any significant difference?
2. How does one handle early binding for custom entities?
3. How does one handle early binding for default entities with custom fields?

There is a lot of links but the most useful I got my mouse on were those. Any other pointers?

[Pro both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008903/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-early-binding)
[Pro early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367411/early-binding-vs-late-binding-what-are-the-comparative-benefits-and-disadvanta)
[Pro late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421168/early-bound-classes-usage)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Some say that early biding is the fastest, other that late is. Is there any significant difference?

   a.  Since Early bound is just a wrapper over the late bound entity class, and contains all the functionality there of, it can't have a faster runtime than late bound.  But, this difference is extremely small and I differ to [Eric Lippert in the What's Fastest type of questions](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).  The one difference in speed that isn't negligible, is the speed of development though.  Early bound is much faster for development, and much less error prone IMHO.
2. How does one handle early binding for custom entities?

   a.  The [CrmSrvcUtil generates the early bound classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx) for custom entities, exactly like the default ones (I created [this tool](https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/) to make generating the classes even easier.  **Update**: It has since moved over to [GitHub](https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/releases) **Update 2** It is now in the XrmToolBox Plugin Store, search for `"Early Bound Generator"` ).  Each time a change is made to a CRM entity, the entity type definitions will need to be updated (only if you want to use a new property or entity, or you've removed a property or entity that you currently use.  You can use early bound entity classes that are out of date, as long as you don't set the values of any properties that don't actually exist, which is the same exact requirements of late bound)
3. How does one handle early binding for default entities with custom fields?

   a.  See the answer to question 2.

One of the little gottcha's when working with early bound entities, is the need to enable early bound proxy types in your `IOrganizationService`.  This is easy for the `OrganizationServiceProxy`, but may take a few more steps for plugins and especially custom workflow activities.

### Edit 1  - My Tests

Below is my code, testing against a pretty inactive local dev environment.  Feel free to test for youself

```cs
using (var service = TestBase.GetOrganizationServiceProxy())
{
    var earlyWatch = new Stopwatch();
    var lateWatch = new Stopwatch();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        earlyWatch.Start();
        var e = new Contact() { FirstName = "Early", LastName = "BoundTest"
        e.Id = service.Create(e);
        earlyWatch.Stop();

        lateWatch.Start();
        var l = new Entity();
        l.LogicalName = "contact";
        l["firstname"] = "Late";
        l["lastname"] = "BoundTest";
        l.Id = service.Create(l);
        lateWatch.Stop();

        service.Delete(e);
        service.Delete(l);
    }

    var earlyTime = earlyWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    var lateTime = lateWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    var percent = earlyWatch.ElapsedTicks / (double)lateWatch.ElapsedTicks;

}
```

My two test results (please note that running two test are not statistically significant to draw any sort of statistical conclusion, but I think they lend weight to it not really being that big of a performance decrease to justify some of the development gains) where ran against a local dev environment with very little other activity to disrupt the tests.

```
Number Creates  |   Early (MS)  |   Late (MS)   |   % diff (from ticks)
10              |   1242        |   1106        |   12.3%
100             |   8035        |   7960        |   .1%
```

Now lets plug in the numbers and see the difference.  12% seems like a lot, but 12% of what?  The actual difference was .136 seconds.  Let's say you create 10 `Contacts` every minute...  .136 x 60 min / hour x 24 hours / day = 195.84 s/day or about 3 seconds a day.  Lets say you spend 3 developer hours attempting to figure out which is faster.  In order for the program to be able to save that much time, it would take 60 days of 24/7 10 contacts / minute processing in order for the faster code to "pay back" it's 3 hours of decision making.

So the rule is, always pick the method that is more readable/maintainable than what is faster first.  And if the performance isn't fast enough, then look at other possibilities.  But 98 times out of 100, it really isn't going to affect performance in a way that is detectable by an end user.

*Premature optimization is the root of all evil* -- DonaldKnuth

Comment: I don't know whom to mark as answer - both you and James gave equivalently useful, well-linked and informative replies. Suggestion?

Comment: Up vote both, and accept one of your choice. The accept is only worth an extra 5 rep. (Basically don't worry about it too much).

Comment: @CRMconfusee  Don't worry about it.  James did answer first,and he does have some killer charts, so I'd give it to him.  Although I'd still recommend the early bound despite the slower performance due to the intellisense and compile time error checking.

Comment: I always roll out the charts when I'm trying to impress :D

Comment: @JamesWood oh snap, just rolled out an ASCII Table... ;)

Comment: You're both worth something. Images and earlier reply gives James the bounty of 50 (it really hurts in my reputational wallet, hehe) and you're getting the green birdy. You're both worth it! This is the kind of question/response that should be protected by the community!

Answer (score 17):

1. Probably not. If you want to know for certain, I would suggest running some tests and profiling the results.

However these MSDN articles suggest late binding it faster.

[Best Practices for Developing with Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509027.aspx)

> Use Early-Bound Types
>
> Use the Entity class when your code must work on entities and
>   attributes that are not known at the time the code is written. **In
>   addition, if your custom code works with thousands of entity records,
>   use of the Entity class results in slightly better performance than
>   the early-bound entity types.** However, this flexibility has a
>   disadvantage because you cannot verify entity and attribute names at
>   compile time. **If your entities are already defined at code time and
>   slight performance degradation is acceptable, you should use the early-bound types** that you can generate by using the CrmSvcUtil
>   tool. For more information, see Use the Early Bound Entity Classes in
>   Code.

[Choose your Development Style for Managed Code for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602917.aspx#entity_programming)

> Entity Programming (Early Bound vs. Late Bound vs. Developer
>   Extensions)
>
> Early Bound ... Serialization costs increase as the entities are
>   converted to late bound types during transmission over the network.

2 & 3. You don't have to take any special action with custom fields or entities. Svcutil will generate classes for both.

[Use the Early Bound Entity Classes in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328210.aspx)

> The class created by the code generation tool includes all the
>   entity’s attributes and relationships. By using the class in your
>   code, you can access these attributes and be type safe. A class with
>   attributes and relationships is created for all entities in your
>   organization. **There is no difference between the generated types for
>   system and custom entities.**

As a side note, I wouldn't get too hung up on it, they are both acceptable implementation approaches and in the majority of situations I doubt the performance impact will be significant enough to worry about. Personally I prefer late binding, but that's mostly because I don't like having to generate the classes.

---

**Edit.**

I performed some quick profiling on this by creating accounts in CRM, a set of 200 & 5000. It confirms the information provided by Microsoft, in both runs late binding was about 8.5 seconds quicker. Over very short runs the late binding is significantly faster - 90%. However early binding quickly picks up speed and by the time 5000 records are created late binding is only 2% faster.

[image: Short Run]

[image: Short Run Data]

[image: Long Run]

[image: Long Run Data]

[Full details blogged here.](http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/crm-2011-early-binding-vs-late-binding-performance/)

Comment: The utility you mentioned - do I need to run it by hand or is it run for me as I compile the code? I was expecting to write my own (or have them generated for me) some data contracts using attributes like `[DataContract] public class MyCustomEntity` etc.

Comment: You run svcutil, that generates all the classes, you include the classes in your project and compile. Remember you will need to regenerate them as your entity model changes.

Comment: The 8.5 seconds seems like a long time to create 10 records.  Are you including the amount of time to create the Organizational Service Proxy?

Comment: 8.5 seconds was the overall difference in run times. E.g. early took 8.5 seconds longer to complete than late. I created the service references up front. I've updated my post to include the raw data so you can see the times for yourself.

Comment: Wow. This reply was a killer! In fact, I'm so wooed that I'l bounty you (and given that I've only got a lousy 350 rep, it's like one-seventh of all my score, so in dog-reputation, is like several hundreds, haha). But this reply deserves it. The check goes to Daryl, though, because I want to reward him too (of course, an image beats a table, hihi). Stop giving such great answers! I can't afford to bounty you all the time. :)